# How do I write a for-loop in Swift 3 for an array that I modify during the for loop?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, for-loop, swift3

So, I have a for-loop that looks similar to this:

```
for var i = 0; i < results.count ; i += 1 {
   if (results[i] < 5) {
      results.removeAtIndex(i)
      i -= 1
   }
}
```

This used to work. But when I changed it to the preferred Swift 3.0 syntax:

```
for var i in 0..<results.count {
   if (results[i] < 5) {
      results.removeAtIndex(i)
      i -= 1
   }
}
```

I get an array IOOBE exception because it doesn't re-check the count and continues on until the original `results.count`.

How do I fix this? It works now, but I don't want to get into trouble in the future.

Comment: this code is not complaining 

for var i in 0..<results.count {
   if (results[i] < 5) {
      results.removeAtIndex(i)
      i -= 1
   }
}

Comment: it makes no sense why apple made the for loop so complex, i never remember having an issue with it for the last 25 year

Answer (score 84, accepted):

While the solution making use of `filter` is a fine solution and it's more *Swift-ly*, there is another way, if making use of `for-in` is, nonetheless, still desired:

```
func removeBelow(value: Int) {
    var results = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

    for i in (0 ..< results.count).reversed() {
        if (results[i] < value) {
            results.remove(at: i)
        }
    }

    print(results)
}

removeBelow(value: 5)
```

Result:

```
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

The problem with `removeAtIndex` within the loop is that it will not cause the array to re-index itself *in-place* and thus causing an array out of bounds exception due to `count` not being updated.

By traversing backwards, the out of bounds exception can thus be avoided.

Comment: Oh god... that's really smart. Yeah I know that the filter way would be more *swiftly* but I think this way applies better, gonna use it. thanks!

Comment: hooray, an editor of an OP that actually provides a well received answer, not just editing to increase rep. rare.

Comment: @Unheiling - .reverse() this function not supported in swift3. Anybody can more help on same question?

Comment: You should remove the `var` keyword in `for var i in (0..<results.count).reverse()`

Answer (score 19):

Could you use a `filter` instead?

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
let greaterThan4 = numbers.filter{$0 >= 5}
print(greaterThan4)
```

Comment: The new array should be named `greaterThan4` ;) Anyway this is the correct way to solve the problem.

Comment: Oh yeah right! the function that calls this is called "filterArray". I never made the connection haha. But I also need the filtered results to be appended to the end. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 15):

If you want to continue using a `for`-loop, you can enumerate over both index and element using `enumerate`:

```
for (index, element) in results.enumerate() {
   if (element < 5) {
     results.removeAtIndex(index)
   }
}
```

Although depending on what you're doing in your loop, the `filter` method might be a better idea.

Comment: That's a bad idea, you will run into the out-of range trap under certain circumstances, for example try the array  `[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`. The reason is that the array is modified in the loop but the index is not adjusted.

Answer (score 1):

If your loop goes forward...

```
for var i in (0..<results.count) where results.indices.contains(i) { 

//if the index doesn't exist, the loop will be stopped.

if (results[i] < 5) {
        results.removeAtIndex(i) 
    }

}
```