# How do you get Xcode 9 to speak phrases in a loop

Tags: swift, xcode

I hope someone can help as I have worked on this problem for hours.  I have an array of phrases. I want to get the app to speak 7 of the phrases starting at the point the user chooses.  This works for one phrase but will not work when I change the position in the array to a variable varied by a For loop.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class view_ViewController: UIViewController {
    var numSubject = 0
    var noteArray = writeString.components(separatedBy: “#”)
    var speakIt = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Fred")
    IBAction func subButtonOne(_ sender: Any) {
        speakIt = AVSpeechUtterance(string: noteArray[numSubject + 1])
        speakIt.rate = 0.5
        synth.speak(speakIt)    }
```

any thoughts?

Comment: Please have a look there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37287261/swift-ios-text-to-speech-not-working-with-delay-in-loop

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = ["1", "2", '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
// replace values in results with your phrases
for var i in (0..<results.count)
{
    if (results[i + numSubject] < results.count)
    {
        print (results[i + numsubject] // call speakIt with this result
        i += 1
    }
}
```

> Modified from [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37624911/9333764)